# "Objects of a category $\mathcal{C}$ constitute a set in some universe"

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

The following is taken from Borceux Handbook of Categorical Algebra p.59:

> Proposition 2.71. Consider the category $\mathcal{C}$ such that, for
> every category $\mathcal{D}$  and functor
> $F:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$, the limit of $F$ exists. In
> that case, $\mathcal{C}$ is just a preordered set.
>
> Proof. Let us use the axiom system of universes (see section 1.1) so that the objects of
> $\mathcal{C}$ constitute a set in some universe...

In section 1.1, we find the following axiom:

> Axiom 1.1.4 Every set belongs to some universe.

Now how does this axiom imply that, for any arbitrary category $\mathcal{C}$, there exists a universe in which $\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ is a set? (What does this even mean? Does this merely mean that for an arbitrary category $\mathcal{C}$ there exists a universe $\mathcal{U}$ such that $\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})\in\mathcal{U}$?)

Comment: "Does this merely mean that for an arbitrary category $\mathcal{C}$ there exists a universe $\mathcal{U}$ such that $\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})\in\mathcal{U}$" short answer: yes

Comment: Ok. Does this follow from Axiom 1.1.4? Or, does it require a tedious set-theoretic cardinality argument?

Comment: I think that the category part is tedious, not the set theory part. But what do I know...

Comment: @alf262 I suppose the text specifies that $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal C)$ is a set in the definition of a category

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti No, it says that $\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ is a class (it could be a proper class).

Comment: Then the author probably specifies that "set" means element of the universe under consideration and "class" means subset of the universe under consideration or something along those lines